# Python Dataframe : append "0" in front of each phone number

Tags: python

I am cleaning csv file using python. My goal is to find any numbers that does not started with 0, and append 0 in front of the number

example existing data :

[image]

Expected output :
0 will be appended to each number that does not start with 0

[image]

My current code :
The logic of the code below is to filter numbers that started with 1 and then append 0 in front of it.

I managed to append zero in from of each number that does not start with zero but I cannot update into data frame.

```
for i in eg1['MOBILENO']:
    if re.findall(r'^["1"]+', i):
        z = "0"+ i
        print(z)
```

Comment: Please don't use images of code and provide (text) examples of code and data

Comment: Please provide (text) examples of code and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following example

```py
df['MOBILENO'] = df['MOBILENO'].apply(lambda x: "0" + x if re.findall(r'^["1"]+', x) else x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It works! . I also find ways to make it save directly into the df but you helped me. thanks a lot

Comment: df.to_csv('test.csv", index=False) - you can save the csv directly

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it worked, check this once.

Indentations were not given properly, check that when you paste the code.

```
for i in range(len(eg1)):
    if eg1.loc[i, 'MOBILENO'][0] != '0':
       x.loc[i,'MOBILENO'] = '0' + x.loc[i,'MOBILENO']
```